# Copy folder and contents based on name , without full path

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, subdirectory, directory-structure

So, i know the tittle is a bit messy, but i cant explain it better

So its easier to understand i'll simulate what i'm facing with

```
C:\A\001\X
C:\A\001\Y
C:\A\001\Z
C:\A\002\X
C:\A\002\Y
C:\A\002\Z
C:\A\003\X
C:\A\003\Y
C:\A\003\Z
```

I have this tree , but i want to copy JUST the "Z" folder from all this locations , giving me something like this

```
C:\A\001\Z
C:\A\002\Z
C:\A\003\Z
```

And its contents as well

If its easier to copy ALL and delete but keep the "Z" folder i'm down for it as well.

I'll keep commenting and posting my "half" answers for a while, or the final answer (if i find it)

Comment: You've posted an incomplete question with absolutely no code. Neither are what I'd deem acceptable on this site. Please edit your question, to include the code you are having a specific replicable issue with, and clarify your question. As currently viewed, you appear to be showing the removal of third level directories not named `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=4,5delims=\" %%w IN ("%%a") DO if /I "%%w%%x"=="Z" ECHO copy %%a
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

The directories to be copied are reported.

Perform a directory scan of the source directory, listing directories only. Take each reported line in its entirety, tokenise it and select the 4th and 5th tokens using `\` as a delimiter. If stringing these two values together results in `Z` then the directoryname has a leaf "Z", so report it.

The directoryname assigned to `%%a` will be each directoryname found, in its entirety.

This name is then tokenised by the `%%w` loop using `\` as a delimiter.

So - The problem, as described is for `C:\A\001\Z` - this appears as `%%a`

C:   is the first token
A    is the second
001  is the third
Z is the fourth

Selecting the fourth and 5th tokens puts the 4th in `%%w` and the fifth in `%%x`.

For `C:\A\001\Z`, we want `%%w` to be `Z` and `%%x` to be empty, so the `if` condition tests precisely that.

Note that in the case of `C:\A\001\Z\X` then the 4th token would be `Z` and the 5th `X`. This is a directory to NOT be selected, so as testing `%%w%%x` would yield `ZX` in this case, and this is not identical to `Z`, the `if` condition excludes that directory.

In the case of your *actual* directories, they are for example `c:\work\tests\001\Z` so you would need to select tokens 5 and 6 instead of 4 and 5 because of the extra directory level.

Now if you actually wanted to locate all of the `Z` leaves, the `for` command would be replaced by simply

```
if /I "%%~nxa"=="Z" ECHO copy %%a
```

That is, if the name-part+extension-part of `%%a` (treating `%%a` as a filename) are exactly `Z` then `echo`.

Note however that this would also report `C:\A\001\Z` if `C:\A\001\Z\X` existed

Comment: Sorry, but even after messing a bit with it it doesnt seems to work, here are the changes i've made


`@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Work\Tests"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=4,5delims=\" %%w IN ("%%a") DO if /I "%%w%%x"=="Z" ECHO copy %%a 
)

GOTO :EOF
`

Comment: inside c:\work\tests i have  001 002 003 004 005.... and inside each one i have some A B C Z folders just for tests

all i want is to end in a folder like c:\work\result\001\z c:\work\result\002\z c:\work\result\003\z